# Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken not working

Tags: c#, azure, oauth, adal, sharepoint-api

```
    // constructor
    public ADALTokenCache(string user)
    {
        // associate the cache to the current user of the web app
        User = user;
        this.AfterAccess = AfterAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeAccess = BeforeAccessNotification;
        this.BeforeWrite = BeforeWriteNotification;

        // look up the entry in the DB
        Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
        // place the entry in memory
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
    }

    // clean up the DB
    public override void Clear()
    {
        base.Clear();
        foreach (var cacheEntry in db.UserTokenCacheList)
            db.UserTokenCacheList.Remove(cacheEntry);
        db.SaveChanges();
    }

    // Notification raised before ADAL accesses the cache.
    // This is your chance to update the in-memory copy from the DB, if the in-memory version is stale
    void BeforeAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        if (Cache == null)
        {
            // first time access
            Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
        }
        else
        {   // retrieve last write from the DB
            var status = from e in db.UserTokenCacheList
                         where (e.webUserUniqueId == User)
                         select new
                         {
                             LastWrite = e.LastWrite
                         };
            // if the in-memory copy is older than the persistent copy
            if (status.First().LastWrite > Cache.LastWrite)
            //// read from from storage, update in-memory copy
            {
                Cache = db.UserTokenCacheList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.webUserUniqueId == User);
            }
        }
        this.Deserialize((Cache == null) ? null : Cache.cacheBits);
    }

    // Notification raised after ADAL accessed the cache.
    // If the HasStateChanged flag is set, ADAL changed the content of the cache
    void AfterAccessNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // if state changed
        if (this.HasStateChanged)
        {
            Cache = new UserTokenCache
            {
                webUserUniqueId = User,
                cacheBits = this.Serialize(),
                LastWrite = DateTime.Now
            };
            //// update the DB and the lastwrite                
            db.Entry(Cache).State = Cache.UserTokenCacheId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            this.HasStateChanged = true;
        }
    }

    void BeforeWriteNotification(TokenCacheNotificationArgs args)
    {
        // if you want to ensure that no concurrent write take place, use this notification to place a lock on the entry
    }
```

This is my code for manage AdalToken Cache 
I got the following exception 
**Failed to acquire token silently. Call method AcquireToken**

got this exception in following code near to **var authResultDisc**

//SharePoint connection to get List Items

```
DiscoveryClient discClient = new DiscoveryClient(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceEndpointUri,
 async () =>
 {
   var authResultDisc = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(SettingsHelper.DiscoveryServiceResourceId, new ClientCredential(SettingsHelper.ClientId, SettingsHelper.AppKey), new UserIdentifier(userObjectId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
             return authResultDisc.AccessToken;
                            });

                            var dcr = await discClient.DiscoverCapabilityAsync("RootSite");
```

my thinking on this is that, it dose not clearing the database entries.

Can any one help me to solve this error.

Comment: The exception seems to suggest trying `AcquireToken` - what happens when you use that?

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected exception if the access token is not able to find in the cache and refresh the access token failed. Please check whether whether you acquire the access token before you call this function.

Comment: What's the function you were trying to retrieve the access token for SharePoint? Please share the code about it and the detailed exception.

Comment: Exception throws at the same line where I am retrieving  the access token for SharePoint. 
one thing I tried that deleted all the databases from the app_data folder
and run my application again, It's starts working again without error

but exception throws again after some days

so my concern is delete all rows from database, next challenge is how to delete all data for that user?

There is the  method Clear() in AdalTokenCache class, but that method is not having any call from entire project. From were we have to call this function to clear the cache from database

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, the exception is expected when `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` function not able to get the access token in the cache and refresh token failed. And the life time of refresh token should be 14 days by default. You should acquire the token interactively again when you get this exception.